# can not send message in cefsharp library in video chat

Tags: webrtc, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

i use cefsharp library in C#.
i have problem in chat websites when i use this library.
for example WEBRTC base video chat i can make video call without any problem but i can't send message in that chat. in some other website my message gonna be send but my friend message would not be sent to me!
for test you can open [luckycrush.live](https://luckycrush.live) and test video chat.
you can see that your message will be send but your friend message showing to you.
can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: Open Devtools and see if there are any errors. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging Are you using geckofx? If not remove the gecko tags.

Comment: @amaitland i get this error in devtools:
`opentok.js:46562 OpenTok:Session:error OT_NOT_CONNECTED: Unable to send signal - you are not connected to the session. +0ms`
AND
`opentok.js:46562 OpenTok:GlobalExceptionHandler:error OT.exception :: title: undefined (500) msg: Unable to send signal - you are not connected to the session. +315ms`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, you'll have to do your own research.